# Replace + with its unicode equivalent in a url

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unicode

I need to test a login process with the beta server and the security policy was updated so that all users have a unique email address.

So I thought for testing the app I would just use this type of email address
 **"myemailaddr+a@gmail.com"**
where the **+a** allows for a unique address.  Then on each subsequent test I would use "+B" etc to ensure I have a unique email address.

All good with the server but when I try and place the URL into my android webView it wont allow me to log in.   Another genuine email address works just fine.

SO, how do I replace a **"+"** in a url string with its Unicode value of **"%2B"** and is it possible to do so in a URL.

Here is the URL template:

```
https://team.mycompany.com/teambeta/Login.aspx?username=myemailaddr+a@gmail.com&password=xxxxxxxx&mobile=1&offSetHours=11&appDevice=AndroidAndroid
```

Is what I am hoping to acheive possible or do I need to go and create multiple unique email addresses for testing?

Answer (score 2):

Use URLEncoder.encode().  See the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Thanks Gabe,  I tried String encodedUserName = URLEncoder.encode(m2tUser, "UTF-8"); but get UnsupportedEncodingException.  I will keep digging and post  the solution once I have nutted it out.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the URL ideas and other suggestions on the net I simply replaced all instances of "+" with "%2B" as follows.

```
 webURL = webURLBefore.replace("+", "%2B");
```

Works well.  And I did not have to encode it as when I did I was strunggling to encode just the "+" and the whole URL was encoded and would not work.
Hope this helps someone.